# Own implementation of memset on Raspberry Pi

Tags: assembly, arm, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I've been playing with writing my own kernel for a Raspberry Pi B+ and I was trying to write my own simple implementation of `memset`. The best solution I could think of (not anywhere close being an expert in assembly language) involved

`stm r0!, {r1,r1,r1,r1,r1,r1,r1,r1}`

where `r0` contains the destination array address and `r1` has the number I'm filling the array with. It seems to work, but the compiler keeps giving me warnings about duplicate registers there. Is there a cleaner/safer/better way to accomplish this?

Comment: You get the warning because you can not use duplicate registers, they will be ignored. You are just writing a single copy of `r1` into memory. Also, `memset` operates on bytes and possibly unaligned addresses, make sure you account for that.

Comment: What's the difference when working with unaligned addresses?

Comment: `STM` and `STR` always write to aligned addresses, the 2 low order address bits are ignored. That means you might be writing below the intended address. You also might get an alignment exception. See the instruction set reference.

Comment: well depending on the arm architecture/core and if alignment checking is enabled as a trap THEN you can get into trouble with stm and str and others.

Comment: get one of the (non cortex-m) arm architectural reference manuals from arm.  infocenter.arm.com (preferrably the armv5 which covers the armv6 in the raspi or the armv7 and look mostly at the armv6 instructions)  and look these instructions up in particular stm.  what you have does a 4 byte write to address contained in r0 or r0-4, with the value in r1.  the ascii syntax for the register values simply sets a bit in the instruction for each register specified, you specified r1 so only one bit is set for that, if you want to write more than 4 bytes with the stm

Comment: then you need to use more registers.  You are on the right track to want to use stm for a memset, but you must deal with alignment.  If you have no idea what we are talking about then the instrucition you want to use in a loop is strb r1,[r0],#1

Comment: So, for instance, assuming the destination array is not aligned I should use `strb` for the first and last few bytes and could use regular `str` in between?

Comment: The CPU is [an ARM11](http://www.broadcom.com/products/BCM2835) according to what I must research.  `stm` is fast but the encoding is always for different registers.  You must set say `r1` to `r9` to zero.  Your best performance will be to align and set a cache line size. The [Linux kernel has an implementation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/lib/memset.S?id=refs/tags/v3.17.1) that might be a good starting point.  `memset` is always *bare metal*, unless you DMA a *zero initialized* buffer multiple times.

Comment: go look at the gcc memset/memcpy implementations, the wheel you are reinventing.  Yes you start in low gear using an strb, and an strh if needed, then you can stm to near the end then an optional strh and strb at the end..

Comment: now the axi bus is probably 64 bit so ideally you want an optional str before you hit high gear and to got cruising speed with stm then work your way back down at the end.  if for example you do a 4 word stm not   64 bit aligned it is likely to turn that into a single 32 bit transfer a 64 bit transfer and a 32 bit transfer if you do a 4 word stm that is aligned then it should result in a single length of 2 (2*64) single transfer.  you should be able to time and measure this difference...

Comment: I know I'm reinventing the wheel, but this is only for learning purposes, so I figured I should try a couple times before looking at someone else's code. Thanks for all the tips (: